# I am not offered option to select master page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, master-pages

Using visual studio 2008. When I add a new aspx form to a project I am not offered the option to choose a master page even though there is one in the project. How do I turn that option on?  It appeared automatically in the past.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you add a new item make sure you select **Web Content Form** and not **Web Form**. Then you'll be able to select the MasterPage.